# Playing Music through Sonos Speaker connected to ETH Raspberry Pi

Tags: wifi, raspberry-pi, ethernet, bridge, router

I have a Raspberry Pi Wifi-to-Ethernet bridge, and have a Sonos Symfonisk speaker plugged into the Ethernet output. In it's current configuration I can't play music through the speaker, is there a WiFi-to-Ethernet tutorial for Linux that would allow me to do this? Thanks!

The ETH output of the Pi can provide access to the internet, but does not seem to allow the device connected to the ETH jack to communicate with other devices on the same network. Even the router just lists the Raspberry Pi as being connected, not the speaker. I'm guessing it has something to do with Multicast?

Comment: "Wifi-to-Ethernet bridge" is very fuzzy. If the Raspberry PI is not the Access Point, then it's not a real bridge like would be an Ethernet-to-Ethernet bridge, but probably involves routing+arp proxy. So what kind of bridge are you talking about? And how is your speaker expected to communicate? Something like Zeroconf/Bonjour/Avahi? And then what "sound" protocol?

Comment: If you want the bridge to be a real bridge, then the RPi has to be the Access Point: for everything, probably meaning overall bandwidth will suffer, or you need a very "open to configure" Access Point, for example: something running Linux + hostapd so both can be configured in 4A mode. Without support from the Access Point, this can't be achieved. And then your question becomes similar to several other questions about bridging Wifi: without answer.